Issue with tbb::task::suspend in nested tbb::task_group
I'm encountering an issue in my C++ program using Intel's Threading Building Blocks (TBB). I have tasks that I want to suspend and continue at a later point, because later this the task might be easier to solve due to changes made by other tasks. My problem is that my program sometimes ends up in some kind of a deadlock.
I wrote a minimal not working example to show how I use tbb. I expected the program to not get stuck.
But Tasks either do not resume correctly or get stuck, indicating a possible issue with the locking mechanism or misuse of the suspend/resume functions.
#include <mutex>
#include <shared_mutex>
#include <tbb/tbb.h>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

class TaskManager {
public:
    using TaskTuple = std::tuple<int, std::vector<tbb::task::suspend_point>>;
    std::vector<TaskTuple> task_tuples;
    std::shared_mutex mtx;

    void addOrSuspendTask(int param) {
        {
            std::unique_lock lock(mtx);
            for (auto& task_tuple : task_tuples) {
                if (std::get<0>(task_tuple) == param) {
                    lock.unlock();
                    tbb::task::suspend([&, param](auto suspend_point) {
                        std::unique_lock inner_lock(mtx);
                        for (auto& inner_task_tuple : task_tuples) {
                            if (std::get<0>(inner_task_tuple) == param) {
                                std::get<1>(inner_task_tuple).push_back(suspend_point);
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                        tbb::task::resume(suspend_point);
                    });
                    return;
                }
            }
            task_tuples.push_back(std::make_tuple(param, std::vector<tbb::task::suspend_point>()));
        }
    }

    void resumeTasks(int param) {
        std::unique_lock lock(mtx);
        for (auto& task_tuple : task_tuples) {
            if (std::get<0>(task_tuple) == param) {
                for (auto& suspend_point : std::get<1>(task_tuple)) {
                    tbb::task::resume(suspend_point);
                }
                std::get<1>(task_tuple).clear();
                std::get<0>(task_tuple) = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};

void exampleTask(TaskManager& manager, int param) {
    if (param > 10) return;
    manager.addOrSuspendTask(param);
     if (param > 8) std::cout << "Executing task with param: " << param << "\n";
    tbb::task_group tg;

    tg.run([&] { exampleTask(manager, param + 1); });
    tg.run([&] { exampleTask(manager, param + 1); });
    tg.wait();
    std::cout << "returning task with param: " << param << "\n";
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
    manager.resumeTasks(param);
}

int main() {
    TaskManager manager;
    tbb::task_group tg;
    tg.run([&] { exampleTask(manager, 1); });
    tg.run([&] { exampleTask(manager, 1); });
    tg.wait();
    return 0;
}

Additional Information:
Compiled with g++ -std=c++17
on WSL Ubuntu with tbb provided by apt:

Package: libtbb-dev
Version: 2021.5.0-7ubuntu2

